# How do I override a \configure statement in html4.4t - tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

This question is a narrowing of one  of the questions I asked in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187246/customizing-tex4ht-to-generate-html-to-convert-to-epub-with-calibre). html4.4t contains this statement:

```
\Configure{float}
   {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
   {\:xhtml{\IgnorePar\EndP}\HCode{<hr class="float"\xml:empty><div
     class="float"\Hnewline>}}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP
    \HCode{</div><hr
        class="endfloat" />}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
```

I tried copying this code into my .cfg file, removing the hr tags. This created an error "Missing $ inserted" right before the \begin{center} when I run tex4t. I then just pasted this verbatim into my .cfg file, but still get the error.

Here's all it takes to see this problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Simple Example}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\hbox{
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
entry1&entry2&entry3\\
entry4&entry5&entry6\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\caption{a caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How do I override this Configure statement to remove the hr tag?

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187246/customizing-tex4ht-to-generate-html-to-convert-to-epub-with-calibre).

The key point is that colon has the wrong catcode to allow :xhtml to be recognized as a command. See the referenced solution for the details and exact code to make it work.