# Which is the .4ht file that controls figure generation in tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht

Does anyone know which .4ht file is used for generating figure HTML output?

The candidates I think are

> html4.4ht:\NewConfigure{figure}{2}
>    tugboat.4ht:\NewConfigure{figure}{2}
>   fig4tex.4ht

Answer (score 6):

`figure` environment isn't configured using `\Configure{figure}`, but with `\ConfigureEnv{figure}`. It must be configured for each output format supported by `tex4ht`, so which one is used depends on the output format. If you use `html`, then configuration from `html4.4ht` is used:

```
\ConfigureEnv{figure}
   {\:xhtml{\IgnorePar\EndP}\HCode{<hr class="figure"\xml:empty><div
     class="figure"\Hnewline>}%
    \bgroup \Configure{float}{\ShowPar}{}{}%
   }
   {\egroup
    \:xhtml{\IgnorePar\EndP}\HCode{</div><hr
       class="endfigure"\xml:empty>}\ShowPar
\par}
   {}{}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187246/customizing-tex4ht-to-generate-html-to-convert-to-epub-with-calibre

Comment: the above link was also useful for the :xhtml tag in .cfg file.

Comment: @daemondave I thought I saw similar question recently, now I know why :)

Comment: @michak.h21 I wanted to customize HTML rendering of `figure` environment by tex4ht and I inserted a modified version of this code in my custom configuration file: `\ConfigureEnv{figure}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<div class="figure">}%
    \bgroup \Configure{float}{\ShowPar}{}{}%
   }
   {\egroup \IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar \par}
   {}{}
`. 
Since it seems to work, I'd like to know if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @mmj it seems fine to me :)